# No logro poner el button como setEnable:NO

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c

Tengo un interfaz con un botón que muestra una imagen cuando esta activo y otra cuando esta desactivado.

Al iniciar la vista siempre aparece el botón como activado a pesar que en el viewDidLoad le hago un [self.button setEnabled:NO]

Si en un momento de la aplicación lanzo un evento y hago un [self.button setEnabled:NO] el botón si se desactiva

¿ Que tengo que hacer para que al inicio me salga el botón como desactivado por código ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba:

[button setEnabled:NO];

y

[button setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]

Comment: Volvi a repasar el código y ahora funciona. Gracias

Comment: Por nada. Saludos desde Paraguay

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacerlo de manera gráfica seleccionando el botón y en el panel de atributos

[image]

Usa este en caso de que necesites que el botón se vea como deshabitado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Usa este en caso de que necesites que se siga viendo igual el botón pero el usuario no pueda realizar ninguna acción sobre el